# rendering a chart into a popup window

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, popup

I have a webapp that renders a chart as per the user input by pulling out the data from a oracle database. I want the chart to be rendered on a new popup window so that the chart is persisted from different user input. i want to do this so that the user can render multiple charts in separate popup windows (with different filters for the data to acquired from the db) with the same button click (multiple clicks and separate filter values of course) and then do comparison between the charts as per they wish. so if there are 10 diff filters and the user wants to see the graphs with any combination of them - he will specify separate filter values each time and hit the button to render the chart in a separate new pop up (and the previous popup with previous chart should persist). 
I am not really good with javascripts. i found some solutions to use modal popups from ajax and some other with the help of javascripts - none of which seems to serve my purpose. any help would be really appreciated.  i am using .net 4.5, asp and c#
thanks.

EDIT 1 (for DJ KRAZE):
So here is the basic layout of my page (sorry that i have to hide most of the part because of security reasons). [image]
As evident all the filters are there to be used to filter out a database and then plot the result as the chart shown. The code behind is absolutely simple C#, nothing fancy. Now what I want is to render that chart in a separate popup window (not attached to the page itself) so that the chart persists if the user decides not to close it and another popup window opens when the user hits submit again with different filter values. so far i have referred to this example and some other javascript related example that does open popups but will not persist if the user has to change the filters -[link to example](http://aj-learning.com/blog/show-gridview-popup-window-asp-net/)

Comment: This would be a question that most will ask on here ... what have you actually tried thus far..can you show code that you have thus far..

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just create any many panels one below another -with a close button- as needed to show the results? 
firing too many popups might clutter the view.

Comment: thats not a bad idea, i will give it a try! but still, it would be nice if you have any idea with popup

Comment: how many popups a user would typically fire? On a laptop screen you have a limited display size to accommodate only a few popups. panels gives you the accommodate any number of popups as the browser would create the scroll automatically. But if a user wants to compare panel1 data with panel7 data - I am not sure how convenient that would be scrolling up and down.

Comment: Yep, thats precisely the reason I want to use popup instead. The screen real-estate is not going to be any issue since most of the users have 3displays(1-laptop and 2 extended monitors summing upto total of about 5k pixels which is more than enough). It would be awesome if I can implement the popus instead of something else.

Comment: best I could think is that you should send data to javascript window  or file that opens in a new  tab so that user can  slide it to monitor 2 or 3 .

Comment: thats my precise plan but couldnt fine proper example/tutorial.. any help ?? :)

Comment: what kind of data you are sending to popup? image only or text plus image? is there any max number of popup a user can fire up?

Comment: I simply want to send the chart image, i am saving the image in the server directory(temporarily) and then i want that image to be displayed into the popup. as of now I dont intend to send anything apart from the image. and I guess i dont want to limit the number of popups allowed per user. :)

Comment: below should solve your problem.

After you have saved the, store image url/path in a variable.

fire  this javascript  from code behind.

function newimg() {

thisimg='<img  src="http://davidfeldmanshow.com/wp->content/uploads/2014/01/dogs-wallpaper.jpg"> ';

newwindow=window.open('','','left=10,top=10,width=400,height=400');

newdocument=newwindow.document;

newdocument.write(thisimg);

newdocument.close();

Comment: here see this in action and also the code 

http://02e34b5.netsolhost.com/youtube/multipopup.aspx

Comment: thanks,i will look into them and let u know, thanks a lot  :)